# Why are rational numbers (Q) the obvious expansion of integers (Z)?

Tags: integers, rational-numbers

BS"D

If we take the set of natural numbers [N] as an example, expanding it to include zero and the negatives so that we get [Z] sounds (and feels) like the next logical step, so I'm okay with that.

But expending [Z] so that we get [Q], that doesn't sit right with me, mostly because of how Q is defined. It seems arbitrary to me. Why choose a quotient of two integers? Why not multiplication? Or, for that matter, any other valid mathematical expression.

Comment: To write BS"D at the top may confuse people who are not used to read things from religious jewish people. Now, your question fits within the realm of abstract algebra, specifically within Ring theory. It is *not* that we "expand" the integers into $\;\Bbb Q\;$, but rather that $\;\Bbb Z\;$ , being an integral domain, has what is called a fraction field, which happens to be $\;\Bbb Q\;$ ... This is very incomplete but hopefully you'll get the picture.

Comment: BS"D Thanks, everyone for all the assistance! I should definitely look more into rings, fields and abstract algebra in general. Thanks once more.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47578/what-to-do-about-religious-salutations If you look here you'll see that for non-religious sites, it is common practice to remove salutations from the beginning of posts (and comments for that matter). Please refrain from using them in the future.

Answer (score 2):

This is all within the more general context of arbitrary rings and fields. In those, we can define other kinds of multiplication, and other kinds of cancellation. We can also build other structures on the integers: we could include an irrational number, or do many other things that would result in something different. We primarily construct the rational numbers from the integers because it is a useful thing to be able to solve an equation like $m\times n=p$.

The integers, $\mathbb{Z}$, have the mathematical structure of a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)). This means that we can add two integers together and we will still get another integer, and we can subtract in order to "undo" addition. However, we can also multiply two integers and the result will always be an integer, but it isn't always possible to "undo" multiplication: Dividing an integer by an integer won't always result in an integer! So, in order to be able to undo multiplication, we construct the rational numbers, $\mathbb{Q}$, which has the special property that it is a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) and also that it is the smallest field (the 'smallest' structure) containing the integers which allows us to divide.

Answer (score 1):

> If we take the set of natural numbers [N] as an example, expanding it to include zero and the negatives so that we get [Z] sounds (and feels) like the next logical step

Consider that  "$\,\mathbb{Z}\,$ is to $\,\mathbb{N}\,$ for addition"  precisely what  "$\,\mathbb{Q}\,$ is to$\,\mathbb{Z}\,$ for multiplication" . The former allows equations like $\,x+a=b\,$ to be solved for arbitrary $\,\forall a,b \in \mathbb{N}\,$. The latter allows equations like $\,x\cdot c=d\,$ to be solved for arbitrary $\,\forall c \ne 0,d \in \mathbb{Z}\,$. So it is a similar "logical step" in that way.

Answer (score 1):

Passing from $\mathbf N$ (which, incidentally, contains $0$) to  $\mathbf Z$  is done, mathematically, to be able to solve  linear equations of the form
$$a+x=b$$
in all cases. This means one tries to have a domain on which the function $x\mapsto x+a$ is invertible, whatever $a$.

The abstract generalisation is the so-called *group defined by a cancellative monoid*.

Quite similarly, for multiplication on $\mathbf Z$, one extends it to be able to solve equations of the form $$ ax=b $$
in all cases for which it makes sense, i.e. when $a\ne 0$. The problem has the same solution for all (commutative) *integral domains*  leading to their *field of fractions*, and is a little more  complex for non-integral domains, leading to their *total ring of fractions*.